# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I am trying to add GXT in my project. For this i followed all the steps given in 
[setting up your first ext gwt project in eclipse](http://www.sencha.com/learn/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse/)

My Java buid path is like this

[image: Java build Path]

My xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
"http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-  module.dtd">
<module rename-to='hellogxt'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>


<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='com.hello.gxt.client.HelloGXT'/>

 <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
 <source path='client'/>
 <source path='shared'/>

 </module>
```

I got this Error

```
  lLoading modules
  com.hello.gxt.HelloGXT
  Loading inherited module 'com.hello.gxt.HelloGXT'
     Loading inherited module 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'
        [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/Generator
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$ClassAttrCvt.convertToArg(ModuleDefSchema.java:884)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerArgs.convertToArg(HandlerArgs.java:64)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:221)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:322)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:493)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:322)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:242)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
     [ERROR] Line 12: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
    com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:325)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:493)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:322)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:242)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
     [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
     com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at        com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:322)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:242)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
     [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
   com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:322)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:242)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
    [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

somebody help me to resolve this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

You should have gxt-2.2.5-gwt2.jar and gxt-2.2.5-gwt22.jar and gxt-2.2.5-gwt17.jar in your class path.

Comment: No, this is wrong (and I'm not sure it solves the problem anyway). You should have *one* of those three jars on your classpath, depending on which version of GWT you are using. As question shows the latest GWT (2.5.1), use *only* the `gxt-2.2.5-gwt22.jar` file.

Comment: i added all the jars . but  still got the same error.. seee the modified image

Comment: @HoucernBerrayans : aadded all the 3 jars : but the error is same.

Comment: After that @ColinAlworth :  i removed 2 jars except gxt-2.2.5-gwt22.jar. but the error is same

Comment: Sorry, @GameBuilder I was trying to point out the major problems that would be added by this answer (i.e. you **must not** have all three gxt jars). I'm not sure of the precise fix though - perhaps you can post the full error and how you got it (i.e. when compiling, when running dev mode, etc)?

Comment: @ColinAlworth : when i run my web application i got the error in console (error are update in in question).
there is nothing in the development mode window.